# Get the filename after find -name | xargs

Tags: grep, terminal, find, xargs

I've a multiple jar directory in which I would like to locate some classes. I found a solution to see if a Class exists with the following command :

```
find -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tf | grep 'myClass'
```

The problem is that I can't see in which `jar` it is located.

I'm looking for a solution to display the filename in my terminal. My current output is like that :

```
[user@server lib]$ find -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tf | grep  'RollOn'  
com/ventyx/utils/logutils/rolling/RollOnDemandAppender.class
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU `grep`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c '
   for file do
     jar tf "$file" | grep -H --label="$file" myClass
   done' sh {} +
```

Or use awk for instance:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c '
   export FILE
   for FILE do
     jar tf "$FILE" | awk '\''/myClass/ {
       print ENVIRON["FILE"] ": " $0}'\''
   done' sh {} +
```

You can also use `bsdtar` (as `jar` files are `zip` files and `bsdtar` supports them) to do the matching by itself (allowing you to have a more verbose output with files metadata without running the risk of `grep` matching on that metadata), though you'd still need something like `grep` to insert the filename:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c '
   for file do
     bsdtar tvf "$file" "*myClass*" | grep -H --label="$file" "^"
   done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, every suggestions seems to work correctly

Comment: Also, instead of `-exec sh ...`, I have developed the preference to pipe the output of `find` into a `while read ...` loop.

Comment: @Pysis, you may want to read [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: As far as newlines goes, for my systems at least, I accept that I should not have files containing that character.  If any do, that is a different problem to solve before any usual other script execution.  Also, I said piping the file lines, and not shoving them in a `for` loop list paramter, so that whitespace is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -exec \
    sh -c 'jar tf "$1" | grep -q "$2" && printf -- '%s\n' "$1"' sh {} 'RollOn' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

With bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*jar; do
    jar tf "$file" | grep -q 'myClass' && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

Or, to print both the file name and the matching line:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*jar; do
    jar tf "$file" | awk -vf="$file" '/myClass/{print f":"$0}'
done
```